# Simple ISEMPTY() function in SQL Server throws a non-boolean type error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a simple `ISEMPTY` function in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ISEMPTY;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION ISEMPTY
    (@charsequence nvarchar(max))
RETURNS BIT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result BIT;

    IF (@charsequence IS NULL OR LEN(@charsequence) = 0)
        SET @result = 1
    ELSE
        SET @result = 0;

    RETURN @result;
END
GO
```

When I want to test it with:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dbo.ISEMPTY('') THEN 'REACHED!' END;
```

I get the following error:

> [S0001][4145] Line 1: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

What goes wrong here?

Comment: `bit` is not a boolean; you can't treat it like one. SQL Server does not have a boolean data type. `bit` is *similar* but it doesn't fulfil the same functionality.

Comment: case when dbo.ISEMPTY('') = 1 then ...   but it seems there are better ways than a SVF

Comment: Perhaps consider something like   coalesce( nullif( someval ,''),'Reached')

Comment: Agreed that a Scalar Value Function may well not be the best choice; especially as they can perform poorly (though they can at least be inlined in SQL Server 2019). The function could, however, be much more succinct. The `RETURN` followed by a `CASE` expression would seem much better, in my opinion. Also, should a string like `' '` return it is empty? It will in the function above.

Comment: Just write `[value] IS NULL OR [value] = ''` at the calling sites. Scalar functions should be used sparingly in T-SQL, as even with inlining the performance is not always optimal, and this use case is too trivial to warrant one. T-SQL should not be treated as a "normal" programming language where it may make sense to encapsulate even small pieces of repeated code; in T-SQL it's not unusual to be forced to duplicate a great deal in the name of performance (or just because the syntax doesn't allow for anything more sophisticated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boolean is expected after `when` in the `case` expression, but your function returns a `bit`.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dbo.ISEMPTY('') = 1 THEN 'REACHED!' END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a number so you need a comparison with a number to get a boolean value

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION ISEMPTY( @charsequence nvarchar(max))
> returns BIT AS
>     begin
>         DECLARE @result BIT;
>
>         IF (@charsequence IS NULL  OR LEN(@charsequence) = 0 ) 
>             SET @result = 1;
>         ELSE
>             SET @result = 0;
>
>         RETURN @result;
>     end
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CASE WHEN dbo.ISEMPTY('') = 1 THEN 'REACHED!' END;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | REACHED!         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e70b34c0900d627818505c415beb6027)*

Comment: As you rolled back the edit; what is an "expre3ssion"?

Comment: Also, what are you quoting here? Can you provide a citation please? And why is `GO` in it's own batch? `GO` in it's own batch seems somewhat pointless. It's just a batch separator, so it doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: i reworte it for better understanding

Comment: @Larnu this comes so from dbfiddle, and stays so,